# Update settings of existing river in Elasticsearch

Tags: mongodb, indexing, elasticsearch-mongo-river

I created `MongoDB` river with index in `Elasticsearch`, but later on noticed that I don't need several fields and I want to use different username/password for river.

How to:
1.Initialize update of river settings for new username/password?
2.Delete/exclude useless fields from index from `Elasticsearch` without rebuilding whole index from the beginning?

I have like 20-30GB of indexed data and whole process of getting data through river may take long hours.
All I found is `Delete` and `PUT`, but there's no update for index fields or river mentioned either in docs or in google.

Answer (score 0):

It's not currently possible to remove a field from a mapping. In order to remove all values of a field from all documents, you need to reindex all documents with this field removed.